# Find inverse function.

Tags: functions

Evertyhing is on the picture. Is [image]

Is it good solution?

Comment: It´s hard to read. Why haven´t you made more effort in your handwriting-not talking about $\LaTeX$.

Comment: It's hard to read. In the definition of $f(x)$ there seems to be a $y$ on the right side, divided by something like a $u$ with a bar over it. For a usual function of $x,$ there would not be another variable like $y$ in its definition.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).